# How to apply t.test to several dataframes?

Tags: r, lapply

I try to generate t.test for 12 dataframes. I try to create a list by doing

```
MyList <- list(data1,data2,data3...,data12)
```

and use lapply to to the t.test. But it is not working. I really don't know what to write...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get all the datasets into a `list`

```
 MyList <-  mget(ls(pattern = "^data\\d+"))
```

then loop over the `list`  and apply `t.test`

```
lapply(MyList, function(x) t.test(x$yourcolumn1, x$yourcolumn2))
```

Make changes with the column name (assuming that the test is applied to the same columns - not clear)